# List all available USB-ports Linux

Tags: usb-drive, raspberrypi

i'm trying to find a way to list NOT plugged devices, but all available usb ports by hardware. I'm working with RPi and it has 4 usb ports , determine by numbers: 1.1.2, 1.3, 1.1.3, 1.2. But i can access this information only when device is plugged. Is there a way to get this numbers not plugging device. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu or Raspbian are you using? How do you access the USB port number information when a device is plugged?

Comment: I'm using the Yocto Zeus branch. Right now I'm parsing the result of "v4l2-ctl --list-devices".

Comment: Yocto Zeus is not an official flavor of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB port information (free or occupied) can be shown by:

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -i -B5 -A3 'logical name: usb'
```

or

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -i -B4 -A3 'usb@'
```

Which shows **output including** (not taken on an RPi):

bus info: usb@3

bus info: usb@4

bus info: usb@4:1

bus info: usb@1

bus info: usb@1:1

bus info: usb@1:1.2

bus info: usb@1:1.4

bus info: usb@2

bus info: usb@2:1

bus info: usb@2:1.5

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I can make use of it.

Comment: @RomanHoncharenko, I updated my answer, as the output from my second grep search was so similar to what you included in your question. Bear in mind the output I show is from my laptop, not an RPi.

Comment: Thanks, I will continue digging in that direction.